# Slick Carousel not working with Foundation 5 and Require JS in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation-5, slick.js

I'm an inexperienced front-end developer, I am currently using **Foundation 5.5** along with Require JS and **Slick Carousel** http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ with smaller pictures so that when they are clicked it goes to the proper slide.

```
 <div class='block-4-img columns medium-8 large-6' data-equalizer-watch>
    <span class='logo-helper'></span>
    <div class='slick-holder columns large-12'>
        <div class='js-slick slick-system'>

            <div class='slide'>
                <img src={{ app.asset_path ~ '/img/new-sales/slick/slick1.jpg'}}></img>
            </div>

            <div class='slide'>
                <img src={{ app.asset_path ~ '/img/new-sales/slick/slick2.jpg'}}></img>
            </div>

            <div class='slide'>
                <img src={{ app.asset_path ~ '/img/new-sales/slick/slick3.jpg'}}></img>
            </div>

            <div class='slide'>
                <img src={{ app.asset_path ~ '/img/new-sales/slick/slick4.jpg'}}></img>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class='slick-buttons'>
            <ul>
                <li><img class='slick-button-1 slick-button' src={{ app.asset_path ~ '/img/new-sales/slick/slick1.jpg'}}></img></li><!-- --><li><img class='slick-button-2 slick-button' src={{ app.asset_path ~ '/img/new-sales/slick/slick2.jpg'}}></img></li><!-- --><li><img class='slick-button slick-button-3' src={{ app.asset_path ~ '/img/new-sales/slick/slick3.jpg'}}></img></li><!-- --><li><img class='slick-button slick-button-4' src={{ app.asset_path ~ '/img/new-sales/slick/slick4.jpg'}}></img></li><!-- --> 
        </div>
    </div><!-- end slick holder -->
</div><!-- block-4-img -->
```

Here is the page I'm currently working on: https://beyondtells.com/silex/new-sales?vero_id=1@1.com (just make sure to keep the query string or it wont show)

It works beautifully in Chrome, which I have been using, I viewed the page in Firefox/IE and it seems that it is not working right. The images inside the carousel are stacked up against each other vertically, and the plugin doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a lot of time trying to figure out what was wrong. I realized the problem was within require JS. I defined a 'preinit' and required it to be with whatever I needed, the method I used was problematic. Here is an example:

`// Append and load styles
        var linkNode = document.createElement("link");
        linkNode.rel = "stylesheet";
        linkNode.type = "type/css";
        linkNode.href = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/0.3.3/sweet-alert.min.css";
        document.head.appendChild(linkNode);`

While this works fine in Chrome, the CSS was not being loaded even though it can be seen in the dev tools. Therefore I simply linked the css file the normal way. Thank you all for taking the time to read my question.